# Proof: For $A_{m×n}$, $rank(AB)=rank(A)$ if $B$ has rank $n$, $rank(CA)=rank(A)$ if $C$ has rank $n$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrix-rank

The [Wikipedia article on matrix rank](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rank_%28linear_algebra%29#Properties) has a properties section that includes the following given that $A$ is $m×n$:

- If $B$ is an $n×k$ matrix of rank $n$, then $rank(AB)=rank(A)$
- If $C$ is an $l×m$ matrix of rank $m$, then $rank(CA)=rank(A)$

I have not seen these results before, and actually was not able to find them mentioned elsewhere after quite a bit of searching, and Wikipedia does not provide or cite proofs. I am wondering what they are based on?

Comment: Depending on your  definition of rank, one could argue that these results are obvious. Please include the definition you are using in your question with an [edit].

Comment: @Brian, can you explain how this can depend on "[my] definition of rank"? I had thought rank was well-defined: the dimension of the column space of a matrix (Wikipedia phrases this in the opening as "the dimension of the vector space generated (or spanned) by its columns"). What alternative definitions would change the understanding of the statements or their proofs?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's an informal explanation that should offer some intuition.

We're given that $A$ is a transformation from $n$-dimensional space to some $\mathrm{rank} (A)$-dimensional part of $m$-dimensional space. As a visualization, picture $A$ being some transformation whose image is plane in $\Bbb R^3$.

We're then told that $B$ is a transformation from a $k$-dimensional space to the $n$-dimensional space and that it has an image of **all** of $n$-dimensional space (i.e. $\mathrm{rank} B = n$). The key observation to make here is that *every* vector that can be input into $A$ can be produced by $B$.

From this, we can see that the composition $AB$ will take vectors from some $k$-dimensional space, map them to the whole of the $n$-dimensional space, and then finally place them in the $\operatorname{rank}(A)$-dimensional subspace of the $m$-dimensional space that $A$ has an an image.

A similar line of reasoning can be used to visualize the meaning of the second statement.